# elegant way for an object composed of other objects to fail in c#

Tags: c#, oop, exception, design-patterns

if you have an object that is composed of a bunch of other objects ie:

```
class A{
  B b {get;}
  C c {get;}
  private A(){
    b = B.Make();
    c = C.Make();
  }
}
```

And classes `B` and `C` are set up to return null when an exception is thrown, is there a better way than mass-checking for null in `A`s members  for null to have it fail as well?

Admittedly my understanding of exception management is poor, but it would make sense for `B` and `C` to not handle their own exceptions and instead let them bubble up to `A`, thereby circumventing the entire null fiasco. But what if they're classes with uses independent of `A`?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? You want any exception to null out all `A`s values?

Comment: if anything in A is bad, A is bad, so yes

Comment: You *could* use reflection, but that would be rather slow and nasty. Why not `null` out all values inside the `catch` block.

Comment: im sure of how you mean to do that

Answer (score 1):

Usually it should be avoided to return null at all, the Make() functions should throw exceptions. If their exceptions are too low level, they should be wrapped in or replaced by custom exceptions.

Now the caller (A) can place the Make() calls in a try-catch block to again replace the exceptions by his own, but he doesn't have to and you don't have to take care of null-checks.

Answer (score 0):

> Admittedly my understanding of exception management is poor, but it would make sense for B and C to not handle their own exceptions and instead let them bubble up to A, thereby circumventing the entire null fiasco. But what if they're classes with uses independent of A?

If B and C can recover from the error in a meaningful way then there is nothing wrong with them handling their own errors. For example, if the must connect to a server, and fail to do so, they could keep trying without having to throw an error. Though obviously you'd want some way to signal their connection state.

So what does this mean for class A? It depends on if A requires a successfully created B and C to be considered to be in a valid state. 
If A needs B or C, then in this scenario (no error thrown) it would be up to A to detect that it isn't in a valid state, and throw (or otherwise handle the error) so that whatever was creating A is aware that A isn't valid.
If A doesn't need B or C, then like B and C in this scenario, you don't have to throw (A is valid), but B and/or C is null, and you will have to check access to it.

**The bottom line is that the behavior of B and C should make sense for B and C. If they should throw, they should throw. *Then* you should worry about A. The behavior of A should likewise make sense for A.**

You seem worried about having to check for null, but which ever path you take (throw, no throw) you'll have to check for *something*. Either you check for null, or you wrap in try catch.

You may also want to consider redesigning class A. Maybe this is a moot point.
Why are B and C contained in class A? Maybe you can simply pass B and C into the public methods of A that need a B or C?